# Seasonality in Keras loss function

Tags: keras, slice, tensor, loss-function

I can't seem to work out how to properly 'slice' arrays/tensors in Keras. I'm writing my own loss function and I want to incorporate a seasonal effect. The simple idea here is to compare values with values of one period ago. In numpy I would write something like this (for a daily period):

```
np.mean(np.abs(y_true[24:] - y_true[-24:]))
```

However, if I want to do the same in the Keras environment like this:

```
K.mean(K.abs(y_true[24:] - y_true[-24:]), axis=-1)
```

I always get a shape mismatch

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes

My question now is this:

how can I write the same inside a Keras loss function, where `y_true` and `y_pred` are no longer np.arrays, but tensors?

Answer (score 0):

Slicing works the same way in tensors as in numpy; the caveat is that tensors have a batch dimension when training / doing inference which is typically undefined when one defines the model.

I would help to know a bit more about the specifics of your model; for instance the question doesn't example the model output dimensions, but for the sake of example if one has a model with an output size of 2 a function that applies an `mse` loss to one output and `mae` to another could be written as:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  err0 = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true[:, 0], y_pred[:, 0])
  err1 = keras.losses.mean_absolute_error(y_true[:, 1], y_pred[:, 1])
  return err0 + err1
```

Usage example:

```
inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,))
out = keras.layers.Dense(2)(inp)
model = keras.models.Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam', custom_loss)

model = make_model()
model.summary()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and to answer your question: my model has an output of 1 dimension. Regarding your answer: It's probably me and I'm maybe overlooking some things, but I fail to see where the periodicity comes into place. Or is that something that just can't be done in a Keras environment?

Comment: The example above shows how to slice an output with a single dimension of size 2. It tries to demonstrate that slicing tensors is equivalent to slicing np arrays. You do not describe in your question the shape of your output. However you do give the impression that the shape is greater than 24 and that you are trying to access the first and last 24 elements. That can be written as a range both in Keras and numpy. The key is that you need to take the batch dimension into account.